# Sorting table according to a single column with multiple values

Tags: interaction-design, tables

[image: Table-sorting]

Have a design related question.

The image shows a sample table sorted according to the column 'Position'. How would one sort the column according to 'Office', with the fields having multiple values.

The solutions I have, at the top of my mind - is.
1. Duplicate rows as user sorts it by Office. Hence a row with 3 values under Office, will appear 3 times in the list. :-/
2. Have 1 main value (Office eg. Tokyo) and the others are secondary values (eg. Bombay,London) so the sorting gets done by the main value only.

Any solutions, suggestions?

Comment: can you elaborate on what is the solution that you chose, and what have the users said about it?    
If you have any more sources/reading material about this problem I would be glad to see it as well.
thanks!

Comment: :( I didn't have a solution. I don't believe I worked on that project long enough to fix this.

Comment: Oh. If you look up Kendo UI controls, I have seen some pretty good solutions for sorting and filtering tables :)

Answer (score 1):

I like your second solution better because:

1. Office locations are consolidated into one column for one person.  This reinforces the notion that the person works out of multiple offices.
2. Out of the possible offices, there must be a main office and sorting by the main office makes sense

One idea you could consider is allowing user to have the option to select sort by. When user clicks on the column header, a droplist will appear that allow user to select either primary or secondary office.

Windows does this in a way, see below:

[image]